# How do i create a heatmap in sns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

i want to make a seaborn heatmap from this data, i have tried but still a bit stuck

```
Unnamed: 0     Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
0      Touba   24   26   27   29   30   30   29   28   28   29   27   23
```

various commands, index, cols

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to set the first column as index.

You can use `set_index`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df.set_index('Unnamed: 0'))
```

But the best would be to correctly read the csv in the first place:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., index_col=0)
sns.heatmap(d)
```

output:

[image: heatmap]